# Partial sign up

Tags: conversion, onboarding

**Trying to figure out whether to go for a one or two step sign-up process for a mobile app.**

**1st step**
Thinking of letting the user to sign up with just the e-mail and password upon which an "User" is created and let inside the app, where it is possible to browse the UI, see what features exist, but not use them, due to financial regulations on KYC.

**2nd step**
For user to start using the features, he must go through the identification flow - pictures of ID, selfie, database checks. (Start of the flow is prompted inside the app, calling to complete the sign-up)

**Pending period**
After the 2nd step is done, there will still be a 1-day pending period where some processing is being made on the background and after that the features are unlocked and all the features are ready to use.

*Why I think it might work:*

- User gets the feel of the app and features showed to him inside the real environment, which would entice to go further with more complex sign-up step, like the identification.

What I'm a bit afraid of:

- Sort of forcing the user out of a flow. There might be users who are sure of the value this product aims to provide beforehand and eager to do the full sign up by ID'ing themselves.
- The pending period results the user basically being back where he was when doing the 1st step. Still can't use the features for some more time. Feels a bit like a false promise that might backfire.

**Any experience if this is a good approach for better conversion?** (Given the premise that what the user sees there inside the app is relevant to the problem he hopes to solve with it)

Comment: We can't really give you a valid answer because we don't know the goal and context of your application. For some apps the above mentioned strategy will be working great while in others it might be a total disaster. Please, provide more details about your app.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about **progressive disclosure**, where the system asks for information from the user only when necessary. It's generally a good way to avoid overwhelming users with long registration forms.

First, ask for a username and password so you can set up the bare account (like you're doing). Then, when users want access to their bank account, you ask for their bank information. When they want to deposit a check via photo, you ask for permission to access their camera. When they want support to call them, you ask for a phone number.

By doing this, you're not only making registration and other processes shorter and easier, but you're asking for information in the context of the user's request. Therefore they're more likely to understand why you're asking for it and more likely to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your concern and that is correct if you let user signup and then again make him wait for verification on the backend, this can certainly drive away lot of users.

Solution to this is you give a heads up about your processes in single go. Also avoid keeping strict 2 step signup. Make it an optional 2 step signup. For the users who want to fill the initial sign up and verification process back to back, let them. For the ones who want to look at the app first, give them a heads up that verification will be required to access features.

Now comes the 1 day of verification process at backend.

To keep users for the time while the backup verification is taking place, you can add a "kickoff timer". So whenever user gets on the app he will encounter with a downgoing timer, hence will be more willing to cling on as the timer solves his uncertainty about verification issue and he now know exactly he can access complete features of the app.

Here you can also use the trick used by lot's of e-commerce websites by surprising the user if the verification process completes before the timer.

Trick in here is you always add 2-4 hrs extra for safety so that every-time your verification will complete before the timer and will provide satisfaction to the customer that you deliver before expected time.

If verification process is taking more time than the timer downtime, show the user proper reason why is it so. Never play with the timer, if the user will notice that you are changing the time at your will, it will drive him away.